# переполнение текстового поля (html, php)

Tags: php, html, html5, переменные, text

Не обычный вопрос. На странице есть некое поле

```
<input type="text" required name="login" size="32" maxlength="64">
```

если оно будет без

```
maxlength="64"
```

то возможно ли неадекватное поведение скрипта который обрабатывает переменную "логин"? Что значит неадекватно?:

ну например передается ооччеенньь большая строка и в скрипте обработки переменная "логин" изменит свой тип, или затрет значения других переменных, или еще что-то странное.

И можно ли обойти ограничение в 64 символа, передавая данные на сервер на со страницы на которой есть это поле, а с помощью не хорошего скрипта.

Да, это вопрос не из категории Сишных, а по теме php.

Comment: Что мешает на сервере проверять длину строки?

Comment: Длинна строк проверяется. Я спрашиваю что будет если не проверять?

Comment: Да. Возможно всё ...

Answer (score 2):

> то возможно ли неадекватное поведение скрипта

возможно, (смотрите скрипт приема данных)

Я в браузере могу изменить любой атрибут любого тега..т.е изменить и задать вашему тегу любую длину какую я захочу и выслать эти данные в скрипт..

Или убрать что это поле required и не заполняя его вовсе - также отправить..

Comment: "Или убрать что это поле required " или браузер будет без поддержки html5. Скрипт обработки данных в порядке! Интересовало какие именно полседствия будут, но "неадакватное" - это, например, НЕ установка (незаполнение) поля - о чем вы написали. Можно по разному понимать значение слова "неадекватное".

Comment: вся адекватность или не адекватность обработки данных ложится на северную часть, поэтому чтобы вы не написали на клиенте т.е. любой HTML и JS всегда в порядке и никак не могут влиять на адекватность поведения или взлом сайта если у вас скрипт обработки данных(php) на 100% в порядке